# Prevent Cordova from creating launch images in iOS platform

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am using **Cordova 6.1.1** and I need to prevent it from creating default launch images in the xcasset of the generated Xcode project.

```
<platform name="ios">
<!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
...
</platform>
```

I removed all entries in the `config.xml` that were referring to the launch images. However Cordova creates the default launch images when this happens.

#### Why

Because I am using a storyboard for launch images, and if I have both the storyboard and launch images, the app at start will display both of them (one after the other).

Where can I specify this setting?

#### Visual studio tools for Cordova

I am actually using the Visual Studio Tools for Cordova. Is there any setting I can tune in this project to achieve this?

Comment: i m not aware of launch images using storyboard. But if that approach does not rely on cordova's default launchscreen mechanism, then you can disable cordova's default launchscreen. you can set the following in config.xml to disable: <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/> Check out this link for more info - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Comment: See if it helps: https://github.com/kerrishotts/cordova-plugin-ios-launch-screen

Comment: @andry just build and see if you removed from config.xml then will not appear at build file check it

Comment: This is still an issue. For reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13024